# Unable to use blitz++ even after installing

Tags: 16.04, c++

I have downloaded and installed blitz using both spack as well as by running the configure file from terminal. However, when I try to remake my code, I always get the following error :

```
fatal error: 'blitz/array.h' file not found
```

After installing blitz, I have installed build-essential and ran the following code as well :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Even then, the fatal error persists. It is the only error that is popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message in your question indicated that you need development package with header file.

According to search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=blitz%2Farray.h) it is located in `libblitz0-dev` package.

Install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libblitz0-dev
```

---

Also please note that it seems to [be packaged with version 0.10-3.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/blitz++) - you can get `libblitz-doc`, `libblitz0-dev`, `libblitz0v5`.

If you are trying to compile newer version then start with getting build-time dependencies of packaged version with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libblitz0v5
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157192/what-do-the-dev-packages-in-the-linux-package-repositories-actually-contain

Comment: after I ran make install, I ran the 1st command to get libblitz0-dev, to which the message pops up saying that there is no installation candidate to install libblitz0-dev. I ran the second command and the message is that it is unable to find a source package for libblitz0v5

Comment: You need to: 1. enable *universe* repository by `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, 2. enable *source code* repositories is Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`).